# Nested Templates (i.e. template <typename T< typename templateArgumentFor_T >>)

Tags: c++, templates

I need to get 2 type-parameters for my class: T1, which is a class that has a template, and T2, which is the parameter for T1's template.

In my case, a Vertex type (there are 2, one inherits from the other), and the data type the vertex stores (name/id in my case).

I want to be able to write something like this:

```
template <   typename VertexType  < typename VertexIDType >    >
```

(which gave me the error: C2143 syntax error: missing ',' before '<')

So that my class would be something like this:

```
class Graph
{
public:    
    Graph(const List<VertexType<VertexIDType>>& verticesList); 
    VertexType<VertexIDType>& getVertexByID(const VertexIDType& ID) const;

private:    
    List<VertexType<VertexIDType>> vertices;
};
```

('List' is my (not std's) implementation for a linked list.)

I also tried `template <typename VertexType, typename VertexIDType>`
but then I got error in the function `Graph(const List<VertexType<VertexIDType>>& verticesList);`
(C2947 expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '<')

and this `template <   typename VertexType  < template <typename VertexIDType> >    >`

(which also gave me error C2143)

I'm really the kind of person that tries to figure everything by himself, but *this* is getting frustrating. I couldn't find an answer that I understood if/how to implement in my code.
I've now finished an OOP (c++) course. I have some experience with templates. I've wrote templates that get 1 or 2 arguments successfully, but nothing like this.

Please help me solve this problem, preferably as elegantly as possible :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use template template parameters:

```
template <template <typename> class VertexType, typename VertexIDType>
class graph;

graph<MyVertexType, MyVertexIDType> //usage
```

Alternatively you could take just a type and extract the ID type in a partial specialization:

```
template <typename Vertex>
class graph;

template <template <typename> class VertexType, typename VertexIDType>
class graph <VertexType<VertexIDType>> {
    //...
}; 

graph<MyVertexType<MyVertexIDType>> //usage
```

Comment: Will the specialization work as expected? As far as I know, the compiler always picks the template with the fewest parameters, which will be `template<typename Vertex>` here.

Answer (score 1):

TartanLlama's answer is a good one for the question that you asked, but you might want to change your approach slightly.  If you require that a `VertexType` must define a typedef `VertexIDType`, then you can write:

```
template <class VertexType>
class Graph
{
public:    
    Graph(const List<VertexType>& verticesList); 
    typedef typename VertexType::VertexIDType VertexIDType;
    VertexType& getVertexByID(const VertexIDType& ID) const;

private:    
    List<VertexType> vertices;
};
```

Note the `typename` in the typedef for VertexIDType.  It is needed to say "this name *must* be a type and not a variable".

Assuming your current VertexType is templated on `VertexIDType`:

```
template <classname VertexIDType>
struct VType1 {
    double stuff; // Or whatever you have in your vertex
};
```

You would need to change it to:

```
template <classname VertexIDType>
struct VType1 {
     double stuff;
     typedef VertexIDType VertexIDType;  // Provide a typedef for VertexIDType.
};
```

This is similar to the approach the standard library takes, where every type which is a *container* has a typedef for `value_type` etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "typedef typename" definition? I did not really understand the syntax. What is the first "VertexIDType" stands for? How would it look like in "VertexType" definition (where I guess you expect it to be, thus the "::")? What is the second "VertexIDType" stands for?

Also, in my code "VertexIDType" is not defined in "VertexType". It is just denoted there as a template argument. It is not a class. It stands for int, long, char, string, etc. or non-standard types (classes), if it will be needed in the future.

Comment: So the idea is to change `VertexType` so that `VertexIDType` *is* defined in it.  Does my edit help?

Comment: @DrorFelman: Is VertexIDType a template argument to VertextType?  If so, that makes it even easier.

Comment: Yes, VertexIDType is a template parameter for class 'Vertex'.
Did you mean doing it with a template, like this:
`template <class VertexIDType>
struct Vertex
{
 typedef VertexIDtype IDType;
 // Body
};`
and then
`template <class VertexType>
class Graph
{
typedef typename VertexType::IDType VertexIDType;
// Body – same as you wrote
};`
And instantiating it like this for example:
`Graph<BasicVertex<char>> g;`

When I think about it, this is a good option as well – extracting the type info from the class itself.